# Selecting and Deleting List View items dynamically through a CAB on a button click, not through long press

Tags: android, listview

I have an application with a list view and a custom adapter where I add custom objects to the list view. I know how to delete objects through long-pressing one of the list items in the list, but I have a trash can action bar button and I want it so that when you click on that button, it brings up the same CAB as if you were long-pressing a list item, and I want the user to be able to select multiple list items, and then click a delete button on the CAB.

What I have tried:

```
package viva.inspection.com.inspectionpicker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import viva.inspection.com.inspectionpicker.R;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    private static ArrayList<InspectionItem> inspections;
    private static final String s = "inspection list";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    ListView inspectionList;
    private final int GET_VALUE=111;
    private final int GET_VAL = 11;
    private MyAdapter listviewadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        inspectionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        inspectionList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        inspections = new ArrayList<InspectionItem>();
        inspections.add(new InspectionItem(new GregorianCalendar(7,15,14), "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", new ArrayList<String>()));
        if(getIntent().getStringExtra("NEW_VALUE") != null) {
            //addItems(getIntent().getStringExtra("NEW_VALUE"));
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
            edit.putString("myKey", TextUtils.join(",", inspections));
            edit.commit();
        }
        if(!(settings.getString("myKey", "hi").equals("hi"))) {
            //We have saved values. Grab them.
        } else {
            //We have no saved values
            inspections = new ArrayList<InspectionItem>();
            inspections.add(new InspectionItem(new GregorianCalendar(7,15,14), "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", new ArrayList<String>()));
        }
        listviewadapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout,
                inspections);
        inspectionList.setAdapter(listviewadapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            case R.id.action_new:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, InitialChoose.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                inspectionList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ActionBarCallBack());
                startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
                //mActionMode.finish();

                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class ActionBarCallBack implements ListView.OnItemSelectedListener, ActionMode.Callback {
        ActionMode activeMode;
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete:
                    // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = listviewadapter
                            .getSelectedIds();
                    // Captures all selected ids with a loop
                    for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                            InspectionItem selecteditem = listviewadapter
                                    .getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                            // Remove selected items following the ids
                            listviewadapter.remove(selecteditem);
                        }
                    }
                    // Close CAB
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cab_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listviewadapter.removeSelection();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(final ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            listviewadapter.toggleSelection(i);
            final int checkedCount = inspectionList.getCheckedItemCount();
            // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
            activeMode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    }

    /*
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == GET_VALUE){
                if(data.getStringExtra("NEW_VALUE")!=null && data.getStringExtra("NEW_VALUE").length()>0){
                    addItems(data.getStringExtra("NEW_VALUE"));
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
                    edit.putString("myKey", TextUtils.join(",", inspections));
                    edit.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    } */
}
```

Basically, with this code, if I click on the trash-can action bar button, the CAB shows up, but I can't select any items on the list and proceed to delete them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Contextual Action Bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one. I used `CheckedTextView`'s for multiple selections inside the list however when the list scrolls the adapter re-uses the old views and sometimes checks the wrong items. To overcome that I used an array of all the currently checked items, so the adapter can know which items should be checked.

Before going back to the original list you need to call notifyDataSetChanged(), which notifies to redrawn the visible views therefore uncheck/delete the selections (depends on what action you chose back at the CAB).

```
package com.example.simon.cabdelete;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Simon on 2014 Jul 18.
 */

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ListView mListView;
    List<String> mListArray;
    SparseBooleanArray mCheckedItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // Default list item click listener
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // Do something on normal click
            }
        });

        mCheckedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
        int size = 20;
        mListArray = new ArrayList<String>(size);
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            mListArray.add("Item "+i);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, mListArray);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                break;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        List<String> items;
        int itemResource;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(ctx, resource, objects);
            this.items = objects;
            this.itemResource = resource;
            this.inflater = ((MainActivity)ctx).getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // (Re)Use convertView
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(itemResource, parent, false);
            }
            CheckedTextView checkView = (CheckedTextView) convertView;

            checkView.setText(items.get(pos));

            if (mCheckedItems.get(pos))
                checkView.setChecked(true);
            else
                checkView.setChecked(false);

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public class ActionBarCallBack implements ListView.OnItemClickListener,
            ActionMode.Callback {

        ActionMode actionMode;
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener previousListener;

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Action mode started");
            actionMode = mode;
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cab_menu, menu);
            previousListener = mListView.getOnItemClickListener();
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            mCheckedItems = new SparseBooleanArray(mListView.getCount());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete:
                    Log.v(TAG, "Deleting "+mCheckedItems.size()+" items");
                    for (int i= mCheckedItems.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                        int key = mCheckedItems.keyAt(i);
                        Log.v(TAG, "Removing array item @ " + key);
                        mListArray.remove(key);
                    }
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Exiting action mode.");
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(previousListener);
            mCheckedItems.clear();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            CheckedTextView checkView = (CheckedTextView) view;
            boolean state = checkView.isChecked();
            checkView.setChecked(!state);

            if (!mCheckedItems.get(position))
                mCheckedItems.put(position, true);
            else
                mCheckedItems.delete(position);

            actionMode.setTitle(mCheckedItems.size() + " Items selected");
            Log.v(TAG, "Action item @ " + position +
                    " clicked. It's state now is " + state);
        }
    }

}
```

And here are my xml files create the whole look:

**res/layout/activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
    <!-- Note that drawSelectorOnTop is important as it lets
     the CheckedTextViews to be clicked in a normal way too-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

**res/layout/list_item.xml**:

```
<CheckedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"/>
```

**res/drawable/list_selector.xml**:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/item_default" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/item_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

**res/values/colors.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <color name="item_default">#33B5E5</color>
    <color name="item_checked">#0095CC</color>
</resources>
```

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this and give you some feedback.